# Grafana - time series Graph not working properly using mysql

Tags: mysql, panel, grafana

i have created one table as below

```
CREATE TABLE consolationstime (TIME_elsp varchar(20),REPONSE_TIME int(11))
```

And values are like:

1. 2019-11-20 08:11:00,    0
2. 2019-11-20 08:11:02,    0
3. 2019-11-20 08:11:02,    6
4. 2019-11-20 08:11:04,    1
5. 2019-11-20 08:11:04,    3
6. ........ ....... ....
7. 2019-11-20 20:11:04,    6

I am try to plot graph using below query but it is not working as expected.

```
SELECT
  unix_timestamp(TIME_elsp) as time_sec,
  max(REPONSE_TIME) as value,
  'REPONSE_TIME' as metric
 FROM CONSOLATIONSTIME
 where REPONSE_TIME != 0
 and $__timeFilter(TIME_elsp) 
 group by TIME_elsp
```

[current graph panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTvhC.png)

Comment: What are you expecting? a simple graph of response time on Y and Time on X ?

Comment: yes, i am expecting output should look like analog graph.